# Number of photos by hashtag

Tags: instagram

On the morning of May 6, 2016 the number of photos to find it was 4000+, the evening count was equal to 2800 and does not change, although the photos are laid out.

https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/@tag/

With what may be related problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are people downvoting this? This is a legitimate (although poorly phrased) question.

I believe it has to do with the update Instagram released yesterday for their layout and search algorithm. The unfortunate side-effect is that tags seem to not include as many pictures as they used to. I'm running a test locally to see what exactly they changed but I suspect they no longer count tags in comments towards the tags of a picture for search purposes.

You used to be able to tag spam in the comments and hit a bunch of different tag "buckets". This behavior wasn't great and lead to a lot of spam, I suspect they only count tags in the original caption as part of the tags attributed to a post.